# How to glue wood pieces together nicely without clamps?

Tags: substitute-tool, time, adhesive

I'm trying to nicely glue together several pieces of wood like pictured below. The tool for this job is a clamp or multiple clamps. I don't have a clamp though. Is there some other way to nicely glue these pieces of wood together without having a clamp? Looking for a way to do this that won't take a lot of extra time, so like only gluing two together at a time, then waiting, then doing another one isn't an option.

[image]

Comment: Is building your own set of clamps an option?

Comment: @Ghost sure, as long as it's not like buy this, and this, and that...etc .. so as long as it's life hackish way to build one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a good looking finished product, nothing will compare to using the correct tools for the job.

That being said you could tie string around the boards and do a tourniquet type thing to tighten them good. Wrap a string around the board, tie a knot at the two ends, close to having the string tight, but not too close. Stick a stick at the knot and twist the stick till the rope is tight. You'll also need to have something heavy across the boards to keep them all flat.

Warning: this will work but will require significant sanding/planing to have a good finished product and having the right clamps for the job will save significant time.

Comment: I'm a little late, but SE just showed this topic for me.  If you use this method, you might want to have some unglued throwaway boards on the ends to prevent the string/strap from damaging the good wood.

Answer (score 1):

1. Take have 4 lengths of scrap wood, and position them like the clamps shown in your picture.
2. Place some weight on top of the 2 top beams. Or, tie the beams on top and bottom together using e.g. luggage straps.